# Jupyter Notebook: First interal link works; subsequent ones do not

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, internal-link

I have the following in a `jupyter` notebook, although not all in the same cell. Every cell set to be markdown type, including the html. The top-most link to `Introduction` works fine, but the others do not. How can we get the second and third link to work properly?

```
# Table of Contents

1. [Introduction](#Introduction)   
2. [Section One](#S_One)  
2. [Section Two](#STwo)  

# Introduction

<a id="#Introduction"></a>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis.

<a id="#S_One"></a>

# Section One

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis. 

<a id="#STwo"></a>

# Section Two

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis. Nam in quam a nisl ornare suscipit in at lacus. Ut tempor mollis fringilla. Etiam eleifend nunc ut ligula condimentum, quis varius sapien convallis. Maecenas placerat turpis at libero egestas, quis lacinia sapien pulvinar. Sed ut dolor vel libero aliquet tristique. Phasellus id facilisis justo.
```

The Actual source is shown below:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# Table of Contents\n",
    "\n",
    "1. [Introduction](#Introduction)   \n",
    "2. [Section One](#S_One)  \n",
    "2. [Section Two](#STwo)  "
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# Introduction"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "<a id=\"#Introduction\"></a>"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis. Nam in quam a nisl ornare suscipit in at lacus. Ut tempor mollis fringilla. Etiam eleifend nunc ut ligula condimentum, quis varius sapien convallis. Maecenas placerat turpis at libero egestas, quis lacinia sapien pulvinar. Sed ut dolor vel libero aliquet tristique. Phasellus id facilisis justo."
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "<a id=\"#S_One\"></a>"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# Section One"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis. Nam in quam a nisl ornare suscipit in at lacus. Ut tempor mollis fringilla. Etiam eleifend nunc ut ligula condimentum, quis varius sapien convallis. Maecenas placerat turpis at libero egestas, quis lacinia sapien pulvinar. Sed ut dolor vel libero aliquet tristique. Phasellus id facilisis justo."
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "<a id=\"#STwo\"></a>"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "# Section Two"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis. Nam in quam a nisl ornare suscipit in at lacus. Ut tempor mollis fringilla. Etiam eleifend nunc ut ligula condimentum, quis varius sapien convallis. Maecenas placerat turpis at libero egestas, quis lacinia sapien pulvinar. Sed ut dolor vel libero aliquet tristique. Phasellus id facilisis justo."
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.6.4"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the reason but I have found that when you create a header with # it automatically creates a link to it. Just place the move over it. The name of the section.

The reason it works with

`1. [Introduction](#Introduction)` and `<a id="#Introduction"></a>`
Is that the name of the section is the same as the automatic link created.

> `1. [Introduction](#Introduction)`
>
> `2. [Section One](#Section-One)`
>
> `2. [Section Two](#Section-Two)`
>
> `# Introduction`
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit
>   amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut
>   ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec
>   dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed
>   velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis.
>
> `# Section One`
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sit
>   amet dignissim ante. Vivamus faucibus iaculis quam id aliquam. Ut
>   ligula metus, lacinia eget finibus in, dignissim nec mauris. Sed nec
>   dolor velit. Aliquam in nisi sit amet mi sagittis egestas ac sed
>   velit. Duis tristique vitae elit ac sagittis.
>
> `# Section Two`
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor

You must put into `(#linkhear)` the value that the mouse over the section gives you.

I hope this helps